# jEdit change PHP highlight background color

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, osx-mavericks, jedit

How to change background color for PHP code in jEdit when mixed with HTML or Javascript or text? I mean how to do something like this screenshot: [dreamweaver example] or suggest any other free editor that does that trick.

[image: dreamweaver example]

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.

Comment: Still doesn't look like programming question!!! You should look at the `Preference` screen for this.

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I'm new in Stackoverflow. I'm reading now the Help Center http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Jedit modes are specified in XML files at your `<jedit installation folder>/modes/*xml`.  Inside of a mode, it may `DELEGATE` from one mode to another.  I.e. the php mode can delegate sections of code to be highlighted by the html mode like:

```
<IMPORT DELEGATE="html::TAGS" />
```

If you could somehow tweak the html mode definition to have a different background, then perhaps you could accomplish this.  See [Writing Edit Modes](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/writing-modes-part.html).

The [Highlight Plugin](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?Highlight) *almost* gives you what you want but it appears to be only a match on a single line with this regex:

```
<\?(.|\n)*?\?>
```

If you tweaked the source code for that plugin to allow multi-line regex matches, then that would get you what you want.